Finding solutions to commutation relation
In a Hilbert space of dimension $d$, a positive definite operator $A>0$ is given. I would be interested in the set of operators $B>0$ such that there exists some $C>0$ that satisfies:
$$i[A,B] + \mathbb{I} = C$$
Is it possible to find a closed form for the operators $B$ satisfying that property in terms of $A$? What must the relationship between $A$ and $B$ (and maybe $C$ ?) be?

Are there any additional properties $A$ and $B$ must have besides being positive definite?

@Callum I cannot think of any right now apart from the fact that they don't commute

I don't know the answer but here are two maybe helpful observations; let's define $S_A:={B>0:i[A,B]+\mathbb{I}>0}$. Then $S_A$ is convex, and it contains all "small enough operators", i.e., all $B>0$ for which $|B|\infty<\frac1{2|A|\infty}$ (because then $|i[A,B]|_\infty<1$). Also positive definiteness of $A$ doesn't play a role here, since shifting $A\to A+\lambda{\bf1}$ leaves the commutator invariant.
